# Combine a web page with files to form one print job?

Tags: php, printing, pdf-generation, html-rendering

I have a page that is tracking transaction information for work. Users upload multiple attachments and complete a form:

I need the user to be able to print the page with attachments as a single print job.

Using FPDF(my Backend is PHP) I should be fine to merge all of the attachments and feed them up - but I am unsure how to merge that with the form data.

I am unfamiliar with constructing PDF files with code - is there a better solution than using the form data to populate a PDF and then combining this with the attachments to create one big PDF, or passing each thing internally through to the printer?

Comment: printing on the user or server side?

Comment: client side would be tremendously preferable

Comment: you can only give the browser one document type, so it would all have to be  converted to one format (pdf?)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I could also maybe convert the PDF's to images and embed them in another web page with the form data formatted?

Comment: sounds possible. if you have smart users, you could give them multiple files? no option sounds ideal here

Comment: The multiple file solution is dangerous since the goal of this app is to make processing these transactions faster - whatever solution I use will be used very repetatively

Comment: basic pdf from html with php is relatively simple, while not a pdf fan, sounds like your best bet, you can easily join multiple pdf files into one